# Regex to find the input tag with submit and value attribute

Tags: c#, regex

I have 2 input tag  like below

```
<input name="daily" value="Next" title="Next"
class="btn btn-link" type="submit"/>

<input type="submit" name="daily" value="Next" title="Next"
 class="btn btn-link"/>
```

I am using

```
<input[^>]*\s*type\s*=\s*('|"|)Submit\s*(\1)[^>]*\s*value\s*=('|"|)Next\s*(\3)[^>]*>
```

But only one is match as per above regex.

I want the regex which match ignoring the position of type or value attribute.

Comment: Base rule: do not use regex for parsing html. Use `HtmlAgilityPack`.

Comment: Your regex is tailor made for the second input.A lot would be needed to change to make it accept first one.Guess its better you make a new one.

Comment: but I want to use regex any how.

Comment: Never ever use regex to parse html. Read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<input[^>]*\s*(?=[^>]*type\s*=\s*('|"|)Submit\s*(\1))[^>]*\s*(?:value\s*=('|"|)Next\s*(\3))[^>]*>
```

Try this.Have added a lookahead which will make sure `type` attreibute is there somewhere in the string not just before `value`
See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/yA5iD9/1

Answer (score 0):

Why you dont use the `?` operator?

```
<input\s*(type="\w+"\s*)?name="\w+"\s*value="\w+"\s*title="\w+"
```

Or in your case use this:

```
<input (type="submit" )?name="daily" value="Next" title="Next"
```